# Why does Rijndael with a 256-bit block require the bottom two rows to be shifted one more space than usual?

Tags: rijndael

From Wikipedia:

> For a 256-bit block, the first row is unchanged and the shifting for the second, third and fourth row is 1 byte, 3 bytes and 4 bytes respectively.

Why the change? Is there any difference than in using 0, 1, 2, 3 like the other keysizes?

Comment: The basic idea is that the block is wider now (8 columns instead of 4 or 6), so we shift more so changes in one column earlier influence all the columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That variation directly implements Rinjdael's ShiftRow as specified (section 4.2.2) in the [proposal to NIST](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf), defining Shitftrows for 128, 192 and 256-bit block size (Nb=4, 6 and 8).

[image: Shitftrows for 128, 192 and 256-bit block size (Nb=4, 6 and 8)]

---

Loosely speaking, the offsets improve the mixing (diffusion) properties of consecutive rounds of the cipher. More precisely the authors state their motivation (section 7.4) as:

> **The ShiftRow offsets**
>
> The choice from all possible combinations has been made based on the following criteria:
>
> 1. The four offsets are different and C0 = 0;
> 2. Resistance against attacks using truncated differentials [[Kn95]](http://www2.mat.dtu.dk/people/Lars.R.Knudsen/papers/trunc.pdf);
> 3. Resistance against the Square attack [[DaKnRi97]](ftp://ftp.esat.kuleuven.ac.be/cosic/rijmen/square/paper/fse.pdf);
> 4. Simplicity
>
> For certain combinations, attacks using truncated differentials can
>   tackle more rounds (typically only one) than for other combinations.
>   For certain combinations the Square attack can tackle more rounds than
>   others. From the combinations that are best with respect to criteria 2
>   and 3, the simplest ones have been chosen.